# Flash movie consuming HTTPS WebService connects as HTTP

Tags: flash, web-services, actionscript-3

I have a Flash Movie (SWF) that is consuming a .NET WebService (located on the same domain) and in my Test environment everything works perfectly (Test env is all HTTP).

When deployed to production (All HTTPS) an issue occurs when trying to access the WebService from the Flash movie.

A new WebService object is created with the HTTPS url passed to it.

myWS = new WebService("https://mydomain/path/to/webservice")

As I watch the HTTP traffic in FireBug I can see the Flash movie making a POST request (passing along the SOAP data) as HTTP (not HTTPS as I would expect). This HTTP requests hits the firewall which forces a 302 Redirect to HTTPS. After this redirect occurs, Flash/Firefox re-sends the request to the HTTPS version of the URL, but as a GET request (thus losing all the SOAP data and making the call to the WebService invalid).

I am trying to figure out how/why a Flash WebService would call a WebService using HTTP even though I am specifically passing it a HTTPS url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that Web Service path in the WebService's WSDL was pointing to HTTP -- even though the WSDL itself was being consumed via HTTPS all subsequent requests to the WebService were HTTP (as specified in the WSDL)

Answer (score 0):

Is the base SWF being loaded int he HTML explicitly via HTTPS? Could be being served via HTTP, perhaps.